# i installed Hadoop in Windows,but when i run hadoop example failed

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm ready to install hadoop on Windows,4 daemons are running,when I run a demo

```
yarn jar %HADOOP_PREFIX%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0.jar wordcount /myfile.txt /out
```

This is my env:jdk1.8 ,hadoop-2.7.7

I get the following error:

```
-_-

D:\ProgramFiles\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.7\share\hadoop\mapreduce>yarn jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar wordcount /myfile.txt /input
19/03/02 10:05:11 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:19000/input already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)

D:\ProgramFiles\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.7\share\hadoop\mapreduce>yarn jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar wordcount /myfile.txt /input1
19/03/02 10:06:25 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
19/03/02 10:06:26 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
19/03/02 10:06:27 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
19/03/02 10:06:27 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1551490342050_0002
19/03/02 10:06:27 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1551490342050_0002
19/03/02 10:06:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://SF80002935M01:8088/proxy/application_1551490342050_0002/
19/03/02 10:06:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1551490342050_0002
19/03/02 10:07:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1551490342050_0002 running in uber mode : false
19/03/02 10:07:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/03/02 10:07:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1551490342050_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1551490342050_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1551490342050_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://SF80002935M01:8088/cluster/app/application_1551490342050_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1551490342050_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (5): ?????



Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: CreateSymbolicLink error (5): ?????



        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Shell output: 移动了         1 个文件。


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
19/03/02 10:07:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0

D:\ProgramFiles\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.7\share\hadoop\mapreduce>hdfs dfs -cat /input1
cat: `/input1': No such file or directory

D:\ProgramFiles\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.7\share\hadoop\mapreduce>hdfs dfs -cat /input1 -r -00000
cat: `/input1': No such file or directory
cat: `-r': No such file or directory
cat: `-00000': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hadoop doesn't overwrite/delete existing data but fails if a file it is told to create already exists. 
The errormessage is quite clear: "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:19000/input already exists". Either delete the directory or choose a diffferent place for your output.

Answer (score 0):

> hdfs://localhost:19000/input already exists

It seems you gave `/input` as the **output** directory for the wordcount of `/myfile.txt`

MapReduce jobs will not overwrite the contents of the output directory if one already exists, and therefore will fail.

---

As for the errors at the bottom, `/input1` would be a directory, and you cannot `cat` a directory, then `-r` and `-00000` are individually not valid output file names.

Instead do `hdfs dfs -ls /input1`, then copy one of the filenames to `cat`